# Error ggplot and ggQC: No geom called label in R with KNIME

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, knime

Here my problem,  i  use library *ggplot2* for displaying a graph which use quality control charts. 
I'm using Knime, precisely R snippet for using my code. When i evaluate my script with *R snippet Knime*, I have this error : `Error : No geom called label`

This is an extract of my code in *R snippet Knime* :

```
library(ggplot2)

Test <-knime.in

require(ggQC)
require(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(Test, aes(x=Day, y=Temperature)) +
  ggtitle("XmR chart Temperature(°C)")+
  xlab("Day")+
  ylab("Temperature(°C)")+
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", color = "blue", geom = c("point")) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", color = "blue", geom = c("line")) +
  stat_QC_labels(method = "XmR") + # label the QC lines 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR") 

print (p)
```

This is the data in `knime.in` :

[image]

After several tests, i found the problem which come from ggQC package, precisely this part of this code :

```
stat_QC_labels(method = "XmR") + # label the QC lines 
stat_QC(method = "XmR")
```

Comment: Could you either give the data that is in `knime.in` or modify the example to use one of the internal datasets so that we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Instead of using `xlab()` and `ylab()`, try to use `labs()` like this : `+ labs( title = "your title", x = "your x axis", y = "your y axis")`

Comment: I try your solution but i have the same error :/

Comment: i'm guessing you might have an old version of ggplot2 that doesn't include  `geom_label`. Try updating your packages

Comment: I try to update the ggplot2 package but i have this error : `ggplot2 is not a valid installed package`